# I didn't know what to answer to my students

Tags: javascript

My students are very beginners.

When I taught them JavaScript, I showed them this function declaration:

```
function test() {
  /* code */
}
```

Then I showed them that you could do some input directly into the console of the Webbrowser.
I then show them arithmetic operations: `1+2`, `6*3` and so on.

One of my students asked me to try this and I was pretty sure it would not work but it did:

```
function test() {
  1+3;
}
```

What could I say to explain this?
And what could I say when you enter some assignation in the command line, like `var i=5;` the return result is `undefined`?

Comment: What was browser name?

Comment: What do you mean by "it did [work]"? That it didn't throw an exception, or that it returned `4`?

Comment: no matter what you do,this will return 13 and not 4..to support you question plz make a fiddle..

Comment: `1+3` is a valid expression, I don't see why that "would not work" as in "throwing an error"

Comment: calling anything that does not return something in the console, will print `undefined`. Calling an expression within a function is valid, so is an arithmetic (as in adding whether it concatenates or whatever..) expression whose result is assigned nowhere.

Comment: @Onaseriousnote: What? `1 + 3 === 4`. You're talking about `1 + "3" === "13"`. Either way, it doesn't **`return`** anything.

Comment: change it to 'return 1+3;' then it would return 4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike some other languages, JavaScript allows expressions as statements, see [§12.4](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.4) *("Expression Statement")* of the specification. So that code is valid, it just doesn't have any enduring effect.

It's the same reason that this works:

```
foo && foo();
```

That's a freestanding expression just like your `1+3;`. In this case, of course, it calls `foo` only if `foo` is not falsey.

[Philipp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1066946/philipp) points out in the comments that ECMAScript5's `"use strict";` is another example of this. Technically in ECMAscript5 it's a *directive*, but it works with pre-ECMAScript5 engines because to them it looks like an expression statement.

> And what could I say when you enter some assignation in the command line, like `var i=5;` the return result is undefined?

Because *statements* don't have a result, only expressions. `var` is a [statement](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.2). If you did them separately, you'd get this:

```
> var i;
undefined
> i=5;
5
```

...because the result of an assignment expression is the value being assigned.

Comment: How ever function just defined and did not called any ware how it can work?

Comment: @antindexer: I assume the OP means "it worked" to mean "it wasn't a syntax error".

Comment: If author of question really mean it. It will work with out problem since it is valid expression. Sorry I did not clearly understand the question.

Comment: Might want to add that `"use strict";` would be an example of this in practice.

Answer (score 1):

When you type something in a browser console you're creating a javascript `Program` (even if it's as small as `3+2`, it's still a program). A program is a sequence of `Statement`s and `FunctionDeclaration`s, separated by (possibly implied) semicolon. JS evaluates all statements and declarations in order and the result of the whole `Program` is the last non-empty result. While `FunctionDeclaration` always yields an empty value (`undefined`), some `Statement`s can return non-empty results. These are listed in the "Statements" section in the standard (http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12), look for the stuff like

```
Return (normal, V, empty) or Return (normal, empty, empty)
```

where the middle part denotes the return value of the statement.

Examples:

```
> var a=1; function x() { 3+1 }
undefined
```

this returns nothing because nether `var` statement, nor a decl have a value.

```
> 3 + 2
5
```

This returns `5`, because expression statements have values.

```
> function x() { 3 + 2 }
undefined
```

This is undefined because `FunctionDeclaration`s don't have values.

```
> var a = 10; while(a>3) a--; function x() {}
4
```

This one returns `4` because `while` does have a value.

```
> var a = 10; if(a>3) a--
10
```

and so does `if`.

Note that while most JS statements do have values, there's no way to obtain or use these values in a JS program (apart from `eval()`, which the console does under the hood). Statements are being evaluated, but their results get lost, and the only real purpose of a statement is to produce side effects. This somewhat strange behavior is a result of Javascript being a functional language (where everything has a value) with procedural syntax. In other words, semantically it would be no problem to allow something like

```
 return if(a > 10) 5 else 0
```

or

```
x = 5 + do { r = nextVal() } while(!used(r))
```

The only reason why this doesn't work is an arbitrary syntactical limitation.

Answer (score 0):

This is an [Expression statement](http://www.2ality.com/2012/09/expressions-vs-statements.html), it is perfectly legal in javascript

All expressions have a return value so:

```
 i = 5 // this is an expression and a statement, returns 5
```

but not all statements are expressions so they may not have return values.

```
 var i= 5; // this is a statement, NOT an expresion, returns undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to return the value you computed and actually call the function, like so:

```
function test() {
    return 1+3;
}
test();
```

What you did was create an expression in your function that evaluated to `4`, but nothing happened to it. Since you didn't return anything in your `test()` function, it would return `undefined` as expected. You didn't call it either, so it would return the result of the last statement. However it doesn't just return the function you created because you only declared it. If you wanted the function object itself, you'd need to wrap parentheses around it or access it later on, like so:

```
function test() { }
test;
```

Or

```
(function test() { });
```

Comment: You didnt get the question, its about why the code runs at all, not why it doesnt return

Comment: In Pluto's defense, it is an easy question to not get.